# Easy XML to HTML table

Tags: html, xml, xslt, html-table

I have an XML file like the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<mylist name="test">
    <title>--$title$- not found</title>
    <table>
        <header>
            <col name="firstname"      title="--$firstname$- not found"/>
            <col name="lastname"      title="--$lastname$- not found"/>
            <col name="country"        title="--$country$- not found"/>
      </header>
            <body>
                <row>
                <col name="firstname">John</col>
                <col name="lastname">Smith</col>
                <col name="country">ENGLAND</col>
              </row>
              <row>
              <col name="firstname">Peter</col>
                <col name="lastname">Scott</col>
                <col name="country">USA</col>
              </row>
        </body>
    </table>
</mylist>
```

and I need to show the result as a HTML table like the following :

[image]

Could anyone help please? I'm not into XML/XSL and I just need this once

Comment: It is easier to provide an answer if you were to post the HTML, rather than an image of the rendered HTML.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more powerful solution that is not only shorter, but produces the correct result even in the case when the `col` elements in the `body` are in mixed order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="mylist">
    <html>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <head>
      <title><xsl:value-of select="." /></title>
    </head>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="header">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tbody>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col[parent::header]">
    <th style="border: solid black 1px;"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col[parent::row]">
    <td style="border: solid black 1px;"><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will actually put a style attribute on each `<td>` or `<th>` which means the output's a little verbose, but it keeps the XSLT nice & simple.

Comment: NP. There are more robust ways of doing it, but if you're not really into XSLT, I decided it was better to make it as simple as I could, rather than add in complexity that solves problems that aren't there.

Answer (score 1):

**This shorter transformation produces the wanted result even if the `col` elements in the `body` are not in the right order**:

--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vColNames">
  <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/header/col">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@name, '|')"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:template match="table">
     <table border="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="header/col">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="body/row">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "col[contains($vColNames,concat('|',@name, '|'))]">
     <xsl:sort select=
     "string-length(substring-before($vColNames, @name))"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="col">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

--

**When applied on this document** (essentially the provided XML document, but the `col` elements in the `body` are in mixed order):

--

```
<mylist name="test">
    <title>--$title$- not found</title>
    <table>
        <header>
            <col name="firstname"      title="--$firstname$- not found"/>
            <col name="lastname"      title="--$lastname$- not found"/>
            <col name="country"        title="--$country$- not found"/>
        </header>
        <body>
            <row>
                <col name="lastname">Smith</col>
                <col name="firstname">John</col>
                <col name="country">ENGLAND</col>
            </row>
            <row>
                <col name="country">USA</col>
                <col name="firstname">Peter</col>
                <col name="lastname">Scott</col>
            </row>
        </body>
    </table>
</mylist>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

--

```
<table border="1">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td>firstname</td>
         <td>lastname</td>
         <td>country</td>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>ENGLAND</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Scott</td>
      <td>USA</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

This might sound a bit flipent... but how about a text editor with find and replace?

XSL is the nicest solution as this is what it was built for.

If you're into scripting then groovy has good XML handling and can probably hack a solution out for you

Comment: if possible XSL yes i could have more than 100rows to display from the xml file..

Answer (score -3):

You mean XSL?

I would avoid XSL if possible and use either your favorite programming language, FreeMarker or perhaps both.